# RxJS: How to set exhaustMap concurrent?

Tags: rxjs

We can use concurrent on mergeMap, but I think it caused a buildup.
Can I set concurrent for exhaustMap ?

```
interval(500).pipe(
  mergeMap(timer(3000), 3)
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve concurrent for exhaustmap.

Comment: exhaustmap ignore value until finish. I want to ignore some values and make sure that a concurrent number of exhaustmap are executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create such an operator yourself. Here is a possible implementation:

```js
const { interval, timer, of, empty } = rxjs
const { mergeMap, map, tap, filter } = rxjs.operators

const exhaustMapWithConcurrency = 
  (selector, concurrency = 1) => 
    source => {
  let active = 0;
  return source.pipe(
    filter(_ => active < concurrency),
    tap(_ => active++),
    mergeMap(selector),
    tap(_ => active--)
  )
}

interval(500).pipe(
  exhaustMapWithConcurrency(x => 
    timer(3000).pipe(
      map(_ => x)
    ), 3)
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could replace that first `mergeMap` with `filter`, I think.

Comment: Also, care needs to be taken with operators that store state: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-managing-operator-state-2f20681df21d I think the answer's implementation will be buggy if there are multiple subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

So I've found a fairly hacky way of achieving what I think you're looking for. In this example, I've used a `toggle` variable, but of course you could use any boolean generator:

```js
toggle = true;
concurrent = 5;

interval(500).pipe(
  filter(() => this.toggle), // are we still accepting values?
  mergeMap((val, index) => {
    // when we hit our concurrency limit, stop accepting values
    if (index % this.concurrent === 0 && index !== 0) {
      this.toggle = false;
    }
    // I added a proportional delay to show that values are ignored
    return of(val).pipe(delay(500 * val));
  }),
  mergeMap((val, index) => {
    // once the preset number of values have been passed down the pipe,
    // meaning our concurrent mergeMaps are complete,
    // start accepting values again
    if (index % this.concurrent === 0 && index !== 0) {
      this.toggle = true;
    }
    return of(val);
  }),
  tap(console.log)
).subscribe();
```

This is, of course, just a demonstration of concept. Does it look like what you're looking for?